# Running code on Release Action from Invoice and Memo screen

Tags: c#, acumatica

I have a customization whereby I want to run some code (a web service call) upon release of an Invoice.  From the training, in my Graph Extension, I utilized and modified the example as follows, where the `CreateAPBills` method is the method I want to run upon the Release Action (ultimately the RowPersisted event):

```
public class ARInvoiceEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<ARInvoiceEntry>
{
    public PXAction<ARInvoice> release;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Release", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
    [PXProcessButton]
    public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<ARInvoiceEntry>((graph) =>
        {
            graph.RowPersisted.AddHandler<ARInvoice>((cache, args) =>
            {
                if (args.TranStatus == PXTranStatus.Completed)
                {
                    CreateAPBill(cache);
                }
            });
        });

        return Base.release.Press(adapter);
    }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work.  What am I missing?

Comment: After talking to someone else about this - I don't necessarily need this to occur on the RowPersisted event - as the Release can happen without necessarily saving, correct?  So, in other words, I need to initiate my code upon the Release action.  Do I still need to add an event handler for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the convention reversed. The PXAction member start with an uppercase letter and the method starts with a lower case letter. Also, try to make your method protected virtual and check if it works.

```
public PXAction<ARInvoice> Release;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Release", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Update, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Update)]
[PXProcessButton]
protected virtual IEnumerable release(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<ARInvoiceEntry>((graph) =>
    {
        graph.RowPersisted.AddHandler<ARInvoice>((cache, args) =>
        {
            if (args.TranStatus == PXTranStatus.Completed)
            {
                CreateAPBill(cache);
            }
        });
    });

    return Base.release.Press(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks much - I see that now.  Unfortunately, I cut and pasted from the T300 course pdf and that's how they show it.  I should have noticed it, though...